# How to properly arrange group plot for bar chart using pgfplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I'm using pgfplot for plotting in Latex. I want to achieve this kind of graph

[image]

And this is the best I can do so far [**Update #4**],

[image]

Here's my latex code [**Updated #4**] :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
       group name=plot,
       group size=2 by 1,
       xlabels at=edge bottom,
       ylabels at=edge left,
       horizontal sep=-10pt,
       vertical sep=0pt,
      /pgf/bar width=12pt},
legend columns=-1,
legend  style={at={(6.5 ,3.6)}},
legend entries={{\color{black}{\footnotesize Win}},{\color{black}{\footnotesize Lose}}},
legend to name=CombinedLegendBar,
ybar legend,
ylabel={Participant},
major x tick style=transparent,
ybar= 1*\pgflinewidth,
ymax=6,
width=6cm,
x axis line style={opacity=0},
x tick label style={rotate=0, anchor=center},
symbolic x coords={{Task 1}, {Task 2}, {Task 3}},
xticklabel style={yshift=-2mm,xshift={ifthenelse(\ticknum==2,0,0)}}, 
xtick=data,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
nodes near coords,
scale only axis,
point meta=explicit symbolic
]

%modifier
\nextgroupplot[
     xlabel=Multiplayer,
     width=0.2\textwidth,
     height=0.2\textwidth,
     enlarge x limits = 0.5]
\addplot[draw=green,thick,fill=green,fill opacity=0.6] coordinates {
  (Task 1,4)[\textcolor{blue!60}{4}]
  (Task 2,4)[\textcolor{blue!60}{4}]
  (Task 3,4)[\textcolor{blue!60}{4}]};

\addplot[draw=orange,thick,fill=orange,fill opacity=0.6] coordinates {
  (Task 1,2)[\textcolor{orange!100}{2}]
  (Task 2,1)[\textcolor{orange!100}{1}]
  (Task 3,3)[\textcolor{orange!100}{3}]};
  
\nextgroupplot[
     xlabel=Single Player,
     yticklabels={,,},
     width=0.13\textwidth,
     height=0.2\textwidth,
     enlarge x limits = 0.5]
\addplot[draw=green,thick,fill=green,fill opacity=0.6] coordinates {
  (Task 1,4)[\textcolor{blue!60}{4}]
  (Task 2,4)[\textcolor{blue!60}{4}]};

\addplot[draw=orange,thick,fill=orange,fill opacity=0.6] coordinates {
  (Task 1,2)[\textcolor{orange!100}{2}]
  (Task 2,1)[\textcolor{orange!100}{1}]};
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\ref{CombinedLegendBar}
```

My problem now :

1. <del>My plot looks untidy, the space between each groupplot also doesn't look nice</del>.
   My solution : set width, height and enlarge x limits for EACH group plot (\nextgroupplot) instead of on global setting (group plot setting). Don't forget "scale only axis" to help modify width and height properly.
2. The dashed line overlapped between two group plot. So what I notice is at the tick of the grid is solid at the end and beginning, that's why when it overlaps with another dashed line, it doesn't look nice.
3. Graph title. I tried to use `\node` to put my title (of all subplots). Doesn't work properly.
4. <del>Is it possible to put my legend on the upper empty space inside of the graph ?</del>   DONE !! Use legend setting and call it with \ref

   Any advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could perhaps do some calculations to get useful widths, see example below. Not sure they're "correct", but the result looked OK.
2. `ytick pos=left` for the first groupplot, `ytick pos=right` for the second.
3. No idea what you mean by "doesn't work properly", adding a node at a useful location works fine. But of course, if you want a numbered caption, use `\caption`.
4. Do you really need `legend to name` and all that? Seems like just adding `legend columns=-1` is enough (given that the height of the diagram is sufficient).

There are also some other modifications, such as making a custom `cycle list`, and setting the style of the `nodes near coords` instead of using `\textcolor` everywhere.

That said, it is also possible to do this with just one `axis`, see second `tikzpicture` in code below.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\NPlotsFirstAx}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\NPlotsSecondAx}{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\SumPlots}{\NPlotsFirstAx+\NPlotsSecondAx+2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\WdFirst}{\NPlotsFirstAx/\SumPlots}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\WdSecond}{\NPlotsSecondAx/\SumPlots}
\begin{groupplot}[
       group style={
       group name=plot,
       group size=2 by 1,
       xlabels at=edge bottom,
       ylabels at=edge left,
       horizontal sep=0pt,
       vertical sep=0pt,
       /pgf/bar width=10pt},
ylabel={Participant},
major x tick style=transparent,
ybar= \pgflinewidth,
ymax=6,
%width=6cm,
x axis line style={opacity=0},
x tick label style={rotate=0, anchor=center},
%symbolic x coords={{Task 1}, {Task 2}, {Task 3}},
xticklabel style={yshift=-2mm,xshift={ifthenelse(\ticknum==2,0,0)}}, 
xtick=data,
xticklabels={Task 1, Task 2, Task 3},
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dotted,
nodes near coords,
scale only axis,
point meta=explicit symbolic,
enlarge x limits = {abs=1},
cycle list={
  draw=blue,thick,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.6,nodes near coords style={blue!60}\\
  draw=orange,thick,fill=orange,fill opacity=0.6,nodes near coords style={orange}\\
  },
legend columns=-1,
height=0.3\textwidth,
]

%modifier
\nextgroupplot[
     xlabel=Color,
     width=\WdFirst\textwidth,
     ytick pos=left
      ]
\addplot  coordinates {
  (1,4)[4]
  (2,4)[4]
  (3,4)[4]};

\addplot  coordinates {
  (1,2)[2]
  (2,1)[1]
  (3,3)[3]};

\nextgroupplot[
     xlabel=Brightness,
     yticklabels={},
     width=\WdSecond\textwidth,
     ytick pos=right
     ]
\addplot coordinates {
  (1,4)[4]
  (2,4)[4]};

\addplot coordinates {
  (1,2)[2]
  (2,1)[1]};

\legend{Win, Lose}
\end{groupplot}


\node [above] at (current bounding box.north) {Title of entire thing};

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xticklabels={Task 1, Task 2, Task 3, Task 1, Task 2},
  xtick=data,
  ylabel={Participant},
  major x tick style=transparent,
  ybar= \pgflinewidth,
  ymax=6,
  x axis line style={opacity=0},
  x tick label style={rotate=0, anchor=center},
  xticklabel style={yshift=-2mm}, 
  xtick=data,
  ymajorgrids=true,
  grid style=dotted,
  nodes near coords,
  scale only axis,
  point meta=explicit symbolic,
  enlarge x limits = {abs=1},
  cycle list={
    draw=blue,thick,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.6,nodes near coords style={blue!60}\\
    draw=orange,thick,fill=orange,fill opacity=0.6,nodes near coords style={orange}\\
  },
  legend columns=-1,
  legend pos=north east,
  height=0.3\textwidth,
  width=0.7\textwidth,
  extra x ticks={2, 5.5},
  extra x tick labels={Color,Brightness},
  extra x tick style={yshift=-15pt},
  title={Title of entire thing}
]

\addplot  coordinates {
  (1,4)[4]
  (2,4)[4]
  (3,4)[4]
  (5,4)[4]
  (6,4)[4]};


\addplot  coordinates {
  (1,2)[2]
  (2,1)[1]
  (3,3)[3]
  (5,2)[2]
  (6,1)[1]};

\legend{Win,Lose}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I clearly see a major difference from our code, yours definitely a lot better. I learned a lot from your answer, thank you ! I will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Final result :

[image]

Addressing my issues :

1. **My plot looks untidy, the space between each `groupplot` also doesn't look nice**. My solution: set `width`, `height` and `enlarge x limits` for EACH of group plot (`\nextgroupplot`) instead of on global setting (group plot setting). Don't forget `scale only axis` to help modify width and height properly.

   ```
   \nextgroupplot[
       xlabel=Single Player,
       yticklabels={,,},
       width=0.13\textwidth,
       height=0.2\textwidth,
       enlarge x limits = 0.5]
   ```
2. **The dashed line overlapped between two group plot. So what I notice is at the tick of the grid is solid at the end and beginning, that's why when it overlaps with another dashed line, it doesn't look nice**. I resize each group plot as small as possible. Actually it doesn't look that bad now.
3. **Graph title. I tried to use \node to put my title (of all subplots). Doesn't work properly.** Wrap tikzpicture in `\begin{figure}` & `\end{figure}` then I can put my title using `\caption`
4. **Is it possible to put my legend on the upper empty space inside of the graph?** DONE!! Use legend setting and call it with `\ref{CombinedLegendBar}`.

   Legend setting:

   ```
   legend columns=-1,
   legend  style={at={(6.5 ,3.5)}, draw=none, column sep=0.2cm},
   legend entries={{\small \color{black}{Succeed}},{\small \color{black}{Fail}}},
   legend to name=CombinedLegendBar,
   ybar legend,
   footnotesize
   ```